# .NET Regular Expression to identify `if .. then .. else .. endif`

Tags: c#, regex

I need two regular expressions to identify `if .. then .. else .. endif` section and their parts.

From an expression which could be like below:

Example 1:

```
5 + 10 * (if (4 + 4.5) > 0 then 20 else 45 endif) + 2
```

Example 2:

```
if (20 == 10) then 10 endif
```

Example 3:

```
if (20/10 != 2) then (2 * 10) else (3 * 4) endif
```

Expected Result:

1. A regular expression which could give me the `if..endif` part in an expression
   For ex. from Example 1 I should receive `if (4 + 4.5) > 0 then 20 else 45 endif` separately
2. A regular expression which could give me the `if..endif` parts.
   For ex. from Example 1 I should receive:

Left-Comparator: `(4 + 4.5)`
Operator: `>`
Right-Comparator: `0`
ThenPart: `20`
ElsePart: `45` (could be null or string.Empty)

Points to Note:

1. `else` is optional.
2. `if..endif` could be the only expression or it could be part of a expression.
3. `then` & `else` can have an expression or a static value.
4. The conditional operators that could be used in if condition are `>, <, ==, !=, >=, <=`
5. Regular Expression should work in **C# application**.

Comment: if i would be the one to do this, i'll do this the 'hard' way.. i'll parsed the thing into lexemes, and do the checking with basic control structures... just a thought!

Comment: Should it handle nested blocks as well (as in `if (if(x==y) then 20 else 10 endif) > 10 then 10 endif`)?

Comment: @Fredrik Mörk: Nope i need for that single condition not nested ifs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regular expressions are not well suited to this kind of job because you can do nested `if`/`then`/`else` and because of the possible variations (lack of `else`, for example); the Regex would be massive and it would take A LOT of work to balance the greediness/laziness of each capture. It would be much easier to scan each character and generate an expression tree that you could then interpret. Regex are more suited to text parsing where the format is known or where there is little variation.

**EDIT**

After thinking about it, it wasn't that hard:

`if( *.*? *)then( *.*? *)(?:else( *.*? *))?endif`

Each capturing group contains the components:

1. The condition
2. Value for true
3. Value for false (only when `else` is present)

I make no guarantees on accuracy, because it doesn't work with nested `if` expressions, but for your needs it should be sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you think you need a regular expression? In a case like this, I would write a small parser, for example using [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/). Maintaining a parser grammar for complex expressions is usually less painful than regular expressions, with the added benefit of providing better error messages with context information and the like.